# Chrome Squishing <img> on browser height resize

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is a weird one!

Working on a cross-browser super simple UI that mimics google docs presentation editor. The issue I've found is for the right portion of the UI, which contains a large slide/image preview and an accompanying 'notes' drawer.

My basic html skeleton:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/business" />        
    </div>

    <div class="otherthing">
        This is another UI thing, 20% height    
    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS to handle fluid scaling with browser resize:

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

*{
    box-sizing:content-box; /* ie */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* all others */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* except firefox */
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.preview{
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}

.preview img{
    height:90%;
    width:auto;    
}

.otherthing{
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background:#369;
}
```

This works in Firefox, Safari, Opera, and IE back to 8! However, in Chrome, if you resize the browser height (just height), the <img> tag gets squished until the browser width is ALSO adjusted. If you resize both width and height, it scales completely fine.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zb5ek/

Anybody have any idea what is going on/what I can do to fix this? It's a dark day when you discover a Chrome-only bug :)

Comment: What version of Chrome is this? Unless I'm mistaken, this works fine in my Chrome (32).

Comment: @Joeytje50 Mac OSX Mavericks, Chrome 32.0.1700.102. Are you on Windows?

Comment: It took a while but I was able to create the issue in Chrome 32. I had to enlarge the window the full way, let go of the mouse and then try to shrink it. Definitely weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.preview img{
    max-height:90%;
    max-width:100%;    
}
```

using max-height and max-width will make it scale proportionally.

Comment: Its a close suggestion, but scaling proportionally means that the greatest obstical is deciding whats more important -width or -height. If all elements need to fit within a 100px width, then width is the greatest issue.  While height could still be set to auto. IMO.

Comment: this definitely fixes it in chrome! ie8, however... it scales proportionally DOWN, but when i scale the browser back up, the image does not scale with it. Nonsense in ie8 = normal though :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You set `height` for `.preview img` as `90%` and `width` to `auto`. But `auto` doesn't mean "match the other size parameter." The [W3C explains `auto`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/width) as meaning "The width depends on the values of other properties."

[The standard gives this explanation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) (relevant portion bolded):

> 10.3.2 Inline, replaced elements
>
> A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes
>   a used value of '0'.
>
> If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the
>   element also has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width is the
>   used value of 'width'.
>
> If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the
>   element has no intrinsic width, but does have an intrinsic height and
>   intrinsic ratio; or if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto',
>   'height' has some other computed value, and the element does have an
>   intrinsic ratio; then the used value of 'width' is:
>
> (used height) * (intrinsic ratio)
>
> If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the
>   element has an intrinsic ratio but no intrinsic height or width, then
>   the used value of 'width' is undefined in CSS 2.1. However, it is
>   suggested that, if the containing block's width does not itself depend
>   on the replaced element's width, then the used value of 'width' is
>   calculated from the constraint equation used for block-level,
>   non-replaced elements in normal flow.
>
> Otherwise, **if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element
>   has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width is the used value of
>   'width'.**
>
> Otherwise, if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the
>   conditions above are met, then the used value of 'width' becomes
>   300px. If 300px is too wide to fit the device, UAs should use the
>   width of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio and fits the
>   device instead.

Comment: Removing `width:auto` doesn't fix the issue so I don't think that is the problem. Unless there is something else you've noticed.

Comment: @MatthewGreen The issue in that scenario is that `width` still has a calculated value of `auto`, so, even if it isn't specified, the problem persists. Defining only one of `width` and `height`, or defining them using different units (`%` vs. `px`) will cause the same problems.

Comment: And that makes sense. The odd part is that even with the width being auto it scales up fine and even down at a certain point. But there is some weird edge case in that the width is not being recalculated as the window is being scaled down from full height.

Comment: While Chrome may indeed be adhering to the specification- it is only in one fringe case (resize of browser height only?). This has all the feel of a browser redraw/recalculation issue, and none of the "I don't know how to follow specifications" issue. I understand the spec- I do not understand the inconsistency in this one specific instance.

Comment: @chrisgonzalez Just to be clear, I'm not criticizing you for how you did this. It's just that Chrome appears to be sticking to the spec here. I can't say whether it will be a problem in other contexts. The way around it is to do what @natewiley suggested or to size the `img`'s container as you want, then leave both `width` and `height` of the image itself to the browser. Then, all browsers should resize it proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

Vexed by this Chrome-only problem several times, I've learned to make an image-specific .css tag. It may not satisfy specs, but it works across all browsers.  At least it does as far as I can determine.

For example, tonight I embedded an image of 222x1048 pixels into a block of text. I decided the image needed to have more height, so I redesigned the graphic to 222x1744 pixels and made appropriate changes in the html.  However, Chrome would not accept the new height value and truncated the image to fit 222x1048.  (as someone wrote, squished it)  BTW, flushing the Chrome cache had zero affect.

The original code read:

```
.rghtimgd
{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin: 11px 0 0 22px;
    clear: left;
}
```

The new code now reads:

```
.rghtimgdxt
{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin: 11px 0 0 22px;
    clear: left;
    height: 1744px;
    width: 222px;
}
```

It's tedious I suppose, but the image now renders properly.  This kind of cross-browser inconsistency drives me to distraction, but I refuse to be stymied by code issues.

Answer (score 0):

width: auto on images is currently still buggy in Chrome.

I filled a bug report here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=503000